# Is there a way to boot into grub on a mac rather then OSX?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, mac

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 on a Mac Mini(late 2014).Now I can get to the new installation by  pressing<kbd>Alt</kbd> > EFI BOOT to get to **GRUB** and selecting Ubuntu to boot the OS. My question is How can I boot into **GRUB** without pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> >**GRUB**. I would like **GRUB** to come up before anything else.

I know some tools like **reFIND** to dual boot with OS X. but, I don't want to install **reFIND** because of various issues like when I install it (My screen goes to black whenever I preform a full shutdown, reFIND still appears but, due to the monitor being off for some reason I cannot see my boot menu. The only way I am able to get my monitor working is to bypass reFIND(which I removed) by reseting the **NVRAM**(Windows Key + <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>R</kbd> +<kbd>P</kbd>).

**What I want:**

I would like **GRUB** to show up like **reFIND**  show up on boot without being triggered by startup manager (or other). I have moved `/boot/efi/EFI/Ubuntu/grubx64.efi` to `/boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi`. I  have tried **refind** but, encountered problems.Note: Both **OS X** and **Ubuntu** installed in EFI mode(and that's the way I'd like to keep it).

So is this even possible?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://glandium.org/blog/?p=2830

Comment: If you figure it out, please come back and answer your own question, in case anyone else has the same issue :)

Comment: Ok. Still looking at it. I destroyed my GPT partition table by accident. and I am trying to restore backups and other stuff

Answer (score 1):

This post at glandium.org might be of interest:

> [Debian EFI mode boot on a Macbook Pro, without rEFIt](http://glandium.org/blog/?p=2830),

as bigbadonk420 pointed out in a comment

This worked for me.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is how, macs either boot in bios/csm or EFI mode, so if the wrong boot mode is selected it wont boot the right away.

1. You can change it by selecting the startup disk, rebooting to macOS is EFI (even if its not macos),
2. the others are BIOS (it is expecting to boot windows) and it will load regular bootloaders.
3. The third option is to have macos-like efi or boot partitions with other bootloaders inside.

If you dont have macos/win installed then use the macos install media to switch the setting.